# even though the xpath is located in the inspect, the error of no such element appears while running

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to find the maximum value from a column of a dynamic web table. but the selenium web driver is not finding the element. but the element is found in the inspecting. 
the maximum value from the column should be displayed.

**error is as follows:**

> FAILED: MaxValue org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]"}

the code is as follows:

```java
package com.selenium;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GettingMaxValueFromDynamicWebTable {

    @Test
    public void MaxValue(){
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:/Programming and 
        qa/QA/selenium/drivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" );
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.phptravels.net/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String row  = "//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr"; 
        int rowData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(row)).size();

        WebElement currentPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* 
        [@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]"));

        String firstPart = "//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr[";
        String secondPart = "]/td[4]";

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 1;i<= rowData;i++){   
            String finalPart = firstPart+i+secondPart;
            System.out.println(finalPart);
            String price = 
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(finalPart)).getText();
            Double dPrice = Double.parseDouble(price);
            int intPrice = dPrice.intValue();
            array.add(intPrice);
        }
        Collections.sort(array);
        System.out.println(array.get(0));
        System.out.println(array.get(array.size()));           
    }          
}
```

Comment: Did you search for this error message? There are already a LOT of blogs and other questions on SO that address this issue. It could be that 1. your locator is wrong, 2. you need to add a wait, 3. it's in an IFRAME, etc. You have to spend some time digging and then come back with the results of your investigations and edit your question to show the results.